# Creating text labels for each row that change based on the alphabet

Tags: python, string, pandas

I'm not quite sure if this is possible but I'll give it a shot.

I have a list of numbers that follows the following format:

```
Number  
008662  
007830  
015549  
008364  
001359
```

What I would like is for these number for have some textual label. For example:

```
Number  Label
008662  sopa
007830  sopb
015549  sopc
008364  sopd
001359  sope
```

the tricky part is my dataframe has 632 rows so i would need to be able to have some labels say `aa, ab, bc` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `string.ascii_letters`

```
import string

df['Label']='sop'+pd.Series(list(string.ascii_lowercase)[:len(df)])
df
Out[1206]: 
   Number Label
0    8662  sopa
1    7830  sopb
2   15549  sopc
3    8364  sopd
4    1359  sope
```

For your case you need create the list by using `product`

```
from itertools import product
DF=pd.DataFrame(list(product(list(string.ascii_lowercase),list(string.ascii_lowercase))), columns=['l1', 'l2']).sum(1)

DF.head()
Out[1215]: 
0    aa
1    ab
2    ac
3    ad
4    ae
dtype: object
```

Then you will get

```
df['Label']='sop'+DF[:len(df)]
df
Out[1218]: 
   Number  Label
0    8662  sopaa
1    7830  sopab
2   15549  sopac
3    8364  sopad
4    1359  sopae
```